# AWS SDK PHP - How to load multiple files with one link? How to create a zip file?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-php-sdk

AWS PHP SDK
I have a bucket, and there are folders with the following files:
**folder1** 
-- photo1 
-- photo2 
-- photo3 
-- photo4

**folder2** 
-- pic1 
-- pic2 
-- pic3 
-- pic4

How can I create a download link for these files: photo1, photo4, pic2? Don't download files on a separate link.

One more question. Is it possible to create a zip archive of these files and download it?

Connecting to the cloud looks like this

```php
$s3 = S3Client::factory(array(
    'credentials' => array(
        'key' => '',
        'secret' => '',
    ),
    'signature' => 'v4',
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region' => 'us-east-1',
));
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what is the expected result you hope to get?

Comment: Also, as far as I know there is no direct way to create a ZIP using S3 directly or the SDK. You would have to do that on your end e.g. download the files and create the archive yourself.

Comment: @Onema At this point, users must download files separately, so I would like to create one link and download selected files

Comment: Got it! Then I believe the simplest way would be to create the archive on your end, save it to S3 and then generate a pre-signed URL, that your end user can use to download the archive. See how to generate the pre-signed URL here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/s3-presigned-url.html. Is this along the lines of what you are looking for?

Comment: @Onema I have a photo storage service. The database contains more than 50 photos (in the cloud, not on the server). From 50 photos (or more) user buys  6 photos (random, which chooses). I would like to create a link from 6 selected photos to download. Today it all looks like this  https://b.radikal.ru/b08/1902/f3/533a22e7db00.png

It turns out after the purchase I need to download photos to the server, create an archive, upload to the cloud and give the user a link to download?

Comment: Yes, that is one way you can do it: download photos -> create zip -> upload to another bucket -> generate pre-signed url for download. As far as I know there is no way to create a zip via S3 SDK directly.